# How to read the pdf file using puppeteer.js and display in html?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I hope you are safe.

I'm making one script which perform some scraping in the site. Now issue is, I have one site which has pdf. So I'm not able to read that pdf file using `puppeteer` and `Node.js`.

I'm able to read other text from other links.

What I tried

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function printPDF() {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('https://blog.risingstack.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
   const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });

   await browser.close();
   return pdf
})
```

It will work to add text into pdf, but I need pdf to text.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm module named "pdfreader". You can check that out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you sure this npm will able to read the pdf from Live link? The link can be any. As I checked this npm, this will used to read the pdf from local path. 

In my case: the URL can be like: htttps://anyhost.com/any/path/of/pdf/sample.pdf

Comment: Oh now i got what problem you are facing with. To my research, puppeteer headless mode doesnt support to read pdf's online yet. But there must be a way to turn around. I found this 2 articles that might help you. 1-)https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1872#issuecomment-670735737
2-)https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/299#issuecomment-643384602
First one is for Google Drive Viewer to be able to read pdf's. Second one is for downloading the pdf file first and then doing what ever you want. You can use 'pdfreader' module for 2. alternatife too.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this was possible in Playwright by using Firefox and navigating to a PDF file, which would be opened using PDF.js. However, recent versions of Playwright broken this functionality:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/13157